# How to use standard input stream instead of Console.ReadKey

Tags: c#, console

How to use Stream.Read() instead of Console.ReadKey()?

```cs
while (true)
{
    var c = Console.In.Read();
    Console.WriteLine("input:" + c);
}
```

But the value will only return when the entire line is entered.

I don't want to use Console.ReadKey() to achieve this function. Because this is not good for testing.

So how to monitor the user's key input through the stream? Or by other means.（When not using the interface as much as possible）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework and .NET Core use the Win32 function `ReadConsoleInput` to power `Console.ReadKey()`, which reads a bit of data at a time from the console buffer.

By contrast, using `Console.In` or `Console.OpenStandardInput()` calls the Win32 function `GetStdHandle` and then wraps the handle in a private class `__ConsoleStream`, which internally uses either the `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` Win32 functions, depending on a few things.

By default, the console stream is configured with `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` which echoes each character you type back to the screen. This requires `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` to be set.

The documentation for `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` states:

> The `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` function returns only when a carriage return character is read. If this mode is disabled, the functions return when one or more characters are available.

Therefore, if we want a stream that uses `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`, we need a console handle with these two flags disabled. This can be done like so:

```
static class Win32Console
{
    public static Stream GetConsoleStreamWithImmediateInput()
    {
        var handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

        if (handle.IsInvalid) throw new Win32Exception();

        try
        {
            if (!GetConsoleMode(handle, out var mode)) throw new Win32Exception();

            mode &= ~(ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);

            if (!SetConsoleMode(handle, mode)) throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        catch
        {
            handle.Close();
            throw;
        }

        return new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.Read);
    }

    const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

    const int ENABLE_LINE_INPUT = 0x0002;
    const int ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 0x0004;

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetConsoleMode(SafeFileHandle hConsoleHandle, out int mode);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetConsoleMode(SafeFileHandle hConsoleHandle, int mode);
}
```

This will get you a stream that lets you read one character at a time, even if an entire line has not been entered yet.

Note that this will not print each character to the screen. If you still want that, you will have to echo it yourself.

Comment: May i ask is it may not work on some users’ computers

Comment: Because I can't guarantee precise control over the environment in which the console application runs.

Comment: Try it. These are all standard Windows functions since Windows 2000, though, so I don't expect any odd incompatibilities.